macOS app built without XCode is notarized but `The installation failed`
I am on macOS 14.6 and I would like to notarize an app which I created. First off, the solution proposed here does not work for me. I tried it in detail.  First, I can get the notarization process accepted:
cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % pyinstaller --onefile ToyThelemacus.py
81 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.11.1, contrib hooks: 2024.10
[...]
3650 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.


cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % codesign --deep --force --options=runtime --entitlements ./entitlements.plist --sign 8AB2C11D2047F2B295E096E25ABE327C09929797 --timestamp ./dist/ToyThelemacus
./dist/ToyThelemacus: replacing existing signature
cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % mkdir -p tmp/ToyThelemacus
cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % ditto ./dist/ToyThelemacus tmp/ToyThelemacus/Applications
cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % productbuild --identifier "com.your.pkgname.pkg" --sign FF42D55EDD167D5C6ED617A193A843C57CDB0E8B --timestamp --root tmp/ToyThelemacus / ToyThelemacus.pkg
productbuild: Using timestamp authority for signature
productbuild: Signing product with identity "Developer ID Installer: CICCIO BOMBO (cicciobombo)" from keychain /Users/cicciobombo/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
productbuild: Adding certificate "Developer ID Certification Authority"
productbuild: Adding certificate "Apple Root CA"
productbuild: Wrote product to ToyThelemacus.pkg

cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus %  pkgutil --check-signature ToyThelemacus.pkg
Package "ToyThelemacus.pkg":
   Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple for distribution
   Signed with a trusted timestamp on: 2024-12-10 17:00:17 +0000
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Developer ID Installer: CICCIO BOMBO (cicciobombo)
       Expires: 2027-02-01 22:12:15 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           B2 79 A4 1C 33 86 10 83 88 14 45 B4 81 06 5F CA DB 6D 17 CE 24 3E 
           17 FC 39 86 53 A6 CB 6A BB C0
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2. Developer ID Certification Authority
       Expires: 2027-02-01 22:12:15 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           7A FC 9D 01 A6 2F 03 A2 DE 96 37 93 6D 4A FE 68 09 0D 2D E1 8D 03 
           F2 9C 88 CF B0 B1 BA 63 58 7F
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3. Apple Root CA
       Expires: 2035-02-09 21:40:36 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           B0 B1 73 0E CB C7 FF 45 05 14 2C 49 F1 29 5E 6E DA 6B CA ED 7E 2C 
           68 C5 BE 91 B5 A1 10 01 F0 24

cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % xcrun notarytool submit --apple-id "ciccio.bombo@gmail.com" --team-id "cicciobombo" --password "ciccio-bombo" ./ToyThelemacus.pkg
Conducting pre-submission checks for ToyThelemacus.pkg and initiating connection to the Apple notary service...
Submission ID received
  id: 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
Upload progress: 100,00 % (6,68 MB of 6,68 MB)   
Successfully uploaded file
  id: 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
  path: /Users/cicciobombo/Documents/thelemacus/ToyThelemacus.pkg
cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % xcrun notarytool info --apple-id "ciccio.bombo@gmail.com" --team-id "cicciobombo" --password "ciccio-bombo" 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
Successfully received submission info
  createdDate: 2024-12-10T17:00:30.021Z
  id: 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
  name: ToyThelemacus.pkg
  status: In Progress

cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % xcrun notarytool info --apple-id "ciccio.bombo@gmail.com" --team-id "cicciobombo" --password "ciccio-bombo" 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
Successfully received submission info
  createdDate: 2024-12-10T17:00:30.021Z
  id: 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
  name: ToyThelemacus.pkg
  status: Accepted

cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % xcrun notarytool log --apple-id "ciccio.bombo@gmail.com" --team-id "cicciobombo" --password "ciccio-bombo" 0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "0df19801-1146-4a55-98af-70a861182ab1",
  "status": "Accepted",
  "statusSummary": "Ready for distribution",
  "statusCode": 0,
  "archiveFilename": "ToyThelemacus.pkg",
  "uploadDate": "2024-12-10T17:00:31.627Z",
  "sha256": "481e3ed58f195a9ecc986c38f28f72b850251ce983873d72df51a65205043f40",
  "ticketContents": [
    {
      "path": "ToyThelemacus.pkg",
      "digestAlgorithm": "SHA-1",
      "cdhash": "6c7364dee3abd3440c5109733186be8653cf3c01"
    },
    {
      "path": "ToyThelemacus.pkg/ToyThelemacus.pkg Contents/Payload/Applications",
      "digestAlgorithm": "SHA-256",
      "cdhash": "75655762cf598f92a7526c46950f98055455da88",
      "arch": "arm64"
    }
  ],
  "issues": null
}


cicciobombo@CiccioMac thelemacus % xcrun stapler staple ToyThelemacus.pkg
Processing: /Users/cicciobombo/Documents/thelemacus/ToyThelemacus.pkg
Processing: /Users/cicciobombo/Documents/thelemacus/ToyThelemacus.pkg
The staple and validate action worked!

But then when I double lick on ToyThelemacus.pkg and proceed with the installation, I see the error in the screenshot attached 
Do you know how I could fix this?
Thank you !
:)

Was your app ever a proper .app bundle?
